# Static files in ExpressJS cannot be loaded via Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

In short, Nginx and Node JS are both running on the same server 10.0.0.120. I can access a Node app via http://10.0.0.120:3000, all stylesheets are loaded properly.

I want the Node app to be accessed via 10.0.0.120/abc/ so I had the following Nginx setup in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
location /abc/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;        
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

}

Now that 10.0.0.120/abc/ can reach the Node app but returns without stylesheet loaded because the relative path maps into 10.0.0.120/stylesheets, which obviously does not exist.

On the NodeJS side, I simply used the Express template,in which `public` folder is used for serving static files.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The Node directory tree is shown below

```
Node App
|
|── public
|   ├── images
|   ├── javascripts
│   │   ├── bootstrap.js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   └── jquery.min.js
│   └── stylesheets
│       ├── animate.css
│       ├── bootstrap.css
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
```

How should I change the Nginx setting to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `app.use(express.static('public'))`. Express should recognize without path.join.

Answer (score 0):

1. Exclude `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` from your code.
2. Configure nginx proxy (`conf/nginx.conf` file) similar below.

   ```
   http {
   ...
     server {
       listen 2000;
       server_name localhost;
       root YOUR-APP-PATH/public;

       location / {
         try_files $uri @backend;
       }

       location @backend {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
       }
       ...
   ```
3. Run application on `2000` port. Application with static files will be enable on `3000`.

P.S. I'm a not nginx expert but it's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to serve static files directly by nginx, its more efficient and you can easily manage cache there

```
server {

       listen YOUR_APP_PORT;
       server_name YOUR_SERVER_NAME;

       location /abc/ {
          YOUR_STANDARD_ROUTING_CONFIGURATION
       }

       location ~^\/(images|stylesheets|fonts|javascripts) {
           expires 1M;
           access_log off;
           add_header Cache-Control "public";
           add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
           add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET;
           add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Requested-With,content-type;
           add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
           root YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH/public;
       }   

}
```

Comment: What if I define another location /xyz/ points to a different NodeJS.  How should I define the location to match the static files for /xyz/?  Also this approach assumes that the static files are on the file system accessible to Nginx, this isn't a big issue for the original question but is there a more generic way to do it?